# i2cdetect - set lower speed

Tags: hardware, sensors, smbus

I heard that I must set  lower speed for i2cdetect to get list of more connected deviced to my laptop but I can't find in man how to set lower speed.

Obviously i2cdetect scans different ports at different speed. (I can see it visually as it scans)